# Y axis scaling for visual comparison

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

Can anyone tell me how to get the Y-axis scaling of the two graphs to have the exact same scale and step size to make them comparable at a glance?

I tried to work with scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 2.5, 0.25)), but that doesn't seem to work very well.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
plot_resp <- ggplot(lmm_breath, aes(x = Bpmf, y = ValueZ, fill = Group)) + 
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.75),
      adjust = .9, 
    width = .30, 
    .width = .00,
    justification = -1.1,
    point_colour = NA) + 
  geom_boxplot(
    width = .45, 
    #outlier.shape = NA
    outlier.colour = NA,
    alpha = 0.5,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)
  ) +
  ggdist::stat_dots(
    side = "left",
    justification = 1.3,
    binwidth = .030,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)
  ) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1.2, NA), clip = "off") + theme_tq_dark() + #scale_fill_tq(light)  
  labs(
    title = "",
    y = "Respiratory Regulation Performance",
    x = "" 
  )
plot_resp <- plot_resp + theme_apa()  +scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 2.5, 0.25))
plot_resp
```

[See plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjCHP.png)

Comment: ```scale_y_continuous()``` also has a limits argument, does ```scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2.5), breaks=seq(0, 2.5, 0.25))``` solve your problem? (sorry no R available to check if it works)

Comment: Hey, this is just perfect. You saved my day. Thank you a lot, Omniswitcher. Hartelijk dank voor dit

Comment: likely a solution (be aware of the differences between limits in the scale options (zooming the plot) and xlim in coord_cartesian (excluding data). Faceting (facet_grid) could be helpful too, to compare two plots side by side... however no data and no picture is provided, so we can only guess what your two plots look like.

Comment: Thanks, Beni. This was helpful, too! Great!

Answer (score 0):

My comment as an answer: Adding the limits argument to the scale_y_continuous should fix this problem:

```
plot_resp <- plot_resp + theme_apa()  +scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2.5),
                                                          breaks=seq(0, 2.5, 0.25))
plot_resp
```

@Beni made some good points in his comment `limit` tells scale_y_continuous between which two values the total axis should be. `breaks` tells something about the distance between the breaks. With `limits` it is possible to zoom in or out of the plot, which can give erroneous results.

His second point about `facet_grid` (which is also part of ggplot2) makes it easy to line-up multiple plots for comparison.